# Xcode 'Jump to definition' shows multiple options of same symbol instead of directly jumping to it

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 9.3 when I select 'Jump to definition' on a func/object I get a popup window that asks me which one I would like to select (see below screenshots)

[image: Jump to definition popup window 1]

[image: Jump to definition popup window 2]

This is the same destination, one is just showing the class.

When I try 'Jump to definition' in a new project it works without creating this popup.

Anyone know why this would be happening?

Cheers

Comment: This had to do with multiple targets. Once I removed the UITesting and UnitTesting targets for my app is stopped. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a weird feature in my opinion. It really slows down my work flow because I always have more than 1 target.

Comment: I agree, it's the main reason why I'm holding off on more than one target at the moment.